# NullPointerException when getBackground() of defaulttimebar of exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to change color of player controller buttons of `exoplayer`. I have successfully set the color of such components except `defaulttimebar`. My code of changing their color as following:

```
    ImageButton prevButton =findViewById(R.id.exo_prev);
    prevButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    ImageButton nextButton =findViewById(R.id.exo_next);
    nextButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    ImageButton fforwardButton =findViewById(R.id.exo_ffwd);
    fforwardButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    ImageButton rewindButton =findViewById(R.id.exo_rew);
    rewindButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    ImageButton playButton =findViewById(R.id.exo_play);
    playButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    ImageButton pauseButton =findViewById(R.id.exo_pause);
    pauseButton.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    TextView durationTextView = findViewById(R.id.exo_duration);
    durationTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood));
    TextView positionTextView = findViewById(R.id.exo_position);
    positionTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(MainActivity.mood));
```

for `timebar` I do the following:

```
DefaultTimeBar defaultTimeBar = findViewById(R.id.exo_progress);     defaultTimeBar.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.id.orange_mood_button),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

But I get `NullPointerException`.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.maysiber.halil.ivme1/com.maysiber.halil.ivme.activities.VideoPlayerActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setColorFilter(int,
>   android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setColorFilter(int,
>   android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.maysiber.halil.ivme.activities.VideoPlayerActivity.changeColorOfPlayerIcons(VideoPlayerActivity.java:217)
>                         at com.maysiber.halil.ivme.activities.VideoPlayerActivity.init(VideoPlayerActivity.java:193)
>                         at com.maysiber.halil.ivme.activities.VideoPlayerActivity.onResume(VideoPlayerActivity.java:242)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your logcat

Comment: I re-edit my question to add the logcat of exception